# × Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./store/reducers/rootReducer";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { createFirestoreInstance, getFirestore } from "redux-firestore";
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider, getFirebase } from "react-redux-firebase";
import fsConfig from "./config/fsConfig";
import { firebase } from "firebase/app";

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore }))
    //reduxFirestore(fsConfig),
    //reactReduxFirebase(fsConfig)
  )
);

const rrfProps = {
  firebase,
  config: fsConfig,
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
  createFirestoreInstance
};

//error position=>
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
      <App />
    </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Open terminal, go to root of project, and update your `react-redux-firebase` with this command:

```
npm install react-router-redux@next
```

Reason being that `ReactReduxFirebaseProvider` is not implemented in the 2.4 version of `react-redux-firebase` thus causes issues with it being wrapped around the `<App />` component.

You want to get the 3.0 version of `react-redux-firebase`.